# Responsive columns and the columnizer plugin - How can I stop the text from wrapping/stopping at the certain point?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a little project to learn html/CSS and use the Columnizer plugin.

**The problem:**

The project is a responsive table. If I resize the window the layout changes and adapts to the new window size. I want to prevent the "category titles" from being at the end of a column. For example like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5ITX.png).

Ideally I'd set manual rules. For example make the title stick to the first two rows of the table (and let it only break/split anywhere after that) and make it impossible that the last two lines are alone at the top of a column.

**What I've tried:**

Columnizer includes two CSS classes called "dontsplit" & "dontend" (both apply javascript) that I'm trying to use. According to the documentation it does that:

> Any node that has the CSS class “dontsplit” won’t be split into multiple columns. This is handy to make sure that tables, etc, aren’t chopped in half if they land at the bottom of a column.

&

> Any node that has the CSS class “dontend” will never be put at the end of a column.

The problem is that I can't seem to make it work. For example adding the "dontend" to the Category Title will not change anything. And the dontsplit (I use it in a ) always automatically applies "dontsplit" to everything as if the  wouldn't have a closing tag.

Didn't work:

```
<div class="dontsplit">
<h2>Category Title</h2>
                    <table class="table table-hover" >  
                                <tr><td WIDTH="67%"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="title" >Title Here</a></td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><a href="http://www.google.com" class="title" >Title Here</a></td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><a href="http://www.google.com" class="title" >Title Here</a></td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
</div>
```

How can I use them correctly? Or is there another simple way to do this?

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/vqsd8x16/

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaults = {
            // default width of columns
            width:400px,
```

change in your code to have pixels will fix your problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem change/improve anything for me. Did you try it out?

Comment: I did in jsfidle you provided with
I also did try to add `max-width` and `min-width`